# Propagate user principal from REST to EJB layer

Tags: java, rest, jboss, ejb, resteasy

I am starting an application that uses a REST api which makes calls to an EJB layer on JBoss Wildfly (RestEasy).

The REST services are inside a war which then calls the ejb layer.
I know how to achieve BASIC or any custom form of authenthication on REST with an RestEasy Interceptor that checks Headers etc.
Basically like described here: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/26/jax-rs-resteasy-basic-authentication-and-authorization-tutorial/

The problem now is - this is just a check on the REST facade. Inside the EJB layer I don't know the user that authenticated against the REST service.

To clear this - when using RMI and Remote EJB calls with authentication, the user name is stored in Session Context:

```
@Stateless
public class LoginService {
@Resource
private SessionContext sessionContext;

  public String getCurrentUser() {
    Principal principal = sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal();
    return principal.getName(); //I need this to be the username from REST auth
    //Currently it's anonymous
  }
}
```

Is there a way to propagate the username in some standard way? E.g. putting a custom principal to SessionContext?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Subject's `doAs` method.
[See the JavaDocs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html).

When makings calls from the war to the EJB do it with the authenticated subject's doAs method. This way the subject is propagated to the context of the ejb. (eg. @RolesAllowed will work fine) 
You can  config the authentication in the web.xml as usual if you want.

To get the subject in the war, try this `Subject userSubject=(Subject)PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");`

Comment: This isn't working on Wildlfly 9.0.2. Tried "Stateless Rest" calling "Stateless Session Bean". Tried "Pojo Rest" calling "Stateless Session Bean".  No user principal propagation. W/ @SecurityContext set up, w/ Resteasy specific security configs (resteasy.role.based.security).